# Why is the Jshell not executing Methods cotaining Enum fields?

Tags: java, jshell

I have a simple Class. Zelle is a simple Enum.

```
public class Main {

    public void getZelle (){
        System.out.println(Zelle.RED);
    }
    public static void test(){
        System.out.println(Zelle.Empty);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HEllo World");

    }

}
```

If i want to open these Methods with the Jshell i get the following Errors which I do not understand:

```
jshell> Main.getZelle()
|  Error:
|  non-static method getZelle() cannot be referenced from a static context
|  Main.getZelle()
|  ^-----------^

jshell> Main.test()
|  attempted to use class Main which cannot be instantiated or its methods invoked until variable Zelle is declared

jshell> Main.main(new String[0])
|  attempted to use class Main which cannot be instantiated or its methods invoked until variable Zelle is declared
```

But if I run the main() in the IDE it will print my test() Method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }
```

Comment: You are using non-static methods and accessing them without creating object. access the methods this way: Main main=new Main(); main.test();

Comment: you need to declare the `Zelle` enum in jshell before using it.

Comment: Looks like you want `getZelle()` to be static.

Comment: @shmosel no i want this Method to be non-static.

Comment: @dan1st how do i declare enums in jshell?

Comment: @JAMSHAID where should i create an Object?

Comment: in the main Method

Comment: @lz01 I've posted the code as answer with explaination

Comment: You can declare enums just like classes: `public enum YourEnumName{ YOUR, ENUM_CONSTANTS, GO, HERE }`

Comment: You can't call `Class.instanceMethod` without an instance of `Class`.

Comment: You declare enums in jshell the same way you declare them in Java, the same way you declare anything in jshell.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the non-static methods in a static way. You can call the non-static methods by creating an object of your class. Your code will look like this:

```
public class Main {

public void getZelle (){
    System.out.println(Zelle.RED);
}
public static void test(){
    System.out.println(Zelle.Empty);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("HEllo World");
    Main main=new Main();  // this is the way to create an o object 
    main.getZelle(); //this is how you call a non-static method using class reference
    main.getTest();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Main.getZelle()
```

You are trying to call method `getZelle()` as a static method – which it is not – hence the error message because `getZelle()` is not a static method.

```
Main.test()
```

`test()` is a static method, however it references `Zelle` (which you claim is an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) but you did not post its definition) and *JShell* does not know how to find that `enum`, hence the error message. *JShell* is trying to compile your class `Main` but it cannot since `Main` references `Zelle` and *JShell* cannot find the definition of `Zelle`.

```
Main.main(new String[0])
```

Same problem as with `Main.test()`.

Since I couldn't find the definition of `Zelle` in your question, I guessed what it is and added it to the code that you enter into *JShell* via its editor. The code is below.

```java
enum Zelle {
    Empty, RED
}

public class Main {

    public void getZelle (){
        System.out.println(Zelle.RED);
    }

    public static void test(){
        System.out.println(Zelle.Empty);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HEllo World");
    }
}
```

Now when I enter `Main.main(new String[0])` into *JShell*, the code executes and I get no error messages. Note, however, that `Main.getZelle()` will still cause an error because `getZelle()` is not a static method (as I explained above).

I also recommend that you adopt [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). `Empty` should be `EMPTY`.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your enum `Zelle` and create instance of `Main` class to call non-static methods:

```
enum Zelle {
  RED, Empty
}


final var main = new Main();
main.getZelle();  // RED
Main.test();  // Empty
Main.main(new String[0]); // HEllo World
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Enum into the JShell with jshell Nameofenum.java.